# String searching with Regex

Tags: regex, string, search

I am trying to use regex (which I am just starting with) to find sequences with up to 1 mismatched character. For example the pattern “nan” and the text “banana” I would want to find “ban” and “nan” the former being acceptable with the mismatch with ‘b’ and ‘n’. The problem I am having is making up a regex pattern without resorting to making individual wildcard inserts where I want them.

```
    final String[] patterns = {"[a-z]an", "n[a-z]n", "na[a-z]"};
    final String text = "banana";

    for(String pattern : patterns)
    {
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile(pattern);
        Matcher m = p.matcher(text);

        while(m.find())
        {
            System.out.println(m.start() + " " + m.group());
        }
    }
```

Is what I have as a test which is kind of a clunky way of getting what I want (albeit with some duplicates). For this kind of String Searching with a single mismatch is regex an effective means or should I try modifying traditional algorithms like Horspool or KMP?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately regular expressions are designed to allow you to be very precise in the pattern you intend to match, conversely there is little support of approximate match. However the TRE library was designed exactly for this purpose ( http://laurikari.net/tre/ )